# How can I use App Analytics to determine which device models are using my app?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

In the Google Play console, I'm able to easily determine which Android device models are using my Android apps.  How do I do the same with my iOS apps in the App Store?

For example - How many iPhone XS devices have downloaded my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple's App Store Connect Analytics provide various insights about your app. However, the segregation based on device model type is something that is not made available to publishers.

For details about what data is made available, see this web page:

- [App Analytics - App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/analytics/)

Comment: That Apple still doesn't provide this metric is unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Nimesh's suggestion.

But it requires the following roles "Account Holder", "Admin", "Finance", or "Sales" but as a "developer" one can not see those metrics.

For more information, please follow: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itc623752a8d